# Reading Meta tags dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, seo, meta-tags

Can someone please help me trying to figure out how to simply write the meta tags in an asp.net page.  The meta tags have been inserted in the page and I just want to loop through them and write the keywords tag.  I don't have a probably adding dynamically, just reading.

Answer (score 3):

.

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
// ...
List<HtmlMeta> metas = new List<HtmlMeta>();
foreach (Control c in this.Page.Header.Controls)
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(HtmlMeta))
    {
        HtmlMeta meta = (HtmlMeta)c;
        if (meta.Name == "Keywords")
            meta.Content = "content goes here";
        break;
    }
```

Edited to make useful to your situation...

Comment: It works with any META tag. Just alter the .Name and .Content and it will produce whatever META you need. Failing that, you can always use a LiteralControl and parse the markup manually.

Answer (score 0):

Below link shows you how to manage your Meta tags & even SEO options.

http://www.programminghelp.com/web-development/asp-net/using-sitemap-and-masterpages-to-set-meta-tags-in-asp-net-and-c/